# Order of an element abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do i find the order of $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$? I know the order of $\bar 0$ will be 1 but what about the order of $\bar 1$ and $\bar 2$?

Also how do you find the order of the elements of a 2x2 matrix?

Comment: The skills involved here are addition in $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$, and counting to three. Are you saying you are having trouble with the former, I hope?

Comment: By "the order of the elements of a matrix", do you mean actually the order of the entries or the order of the matrix itself? In the former case, the matrix is irrelevant.

Comment: I don't know what "the order of the elements of a matrix" means. Are you just referring to the "order of the elements"? You could just check them separately. But before you did that, you'd have to explain *where the elements come from.*  If you mean the *order of the matrix* then that is a different question. You'll have to clarify before anyone can help properly.

Comment: Is the order of 1bar 0 because 0x1=0 and same with 2bar since its addition but that doesnt seem right does it.

Comment: @user504498 And if you want to know about the *order of elements* you should not say "order of $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$," because that has a different meaning.

Answer (score 2):

$\bar 1\neq \bar 0$

$\bar 1+\bar 1=\bar 2\neq \bar 0$

$\bar 1 +\bar 1+\bar 1 = \bar 3 = \bar 0$.

So the order of $\bar 1$ is $3$.

I leave the other one to you.

(awaiting clarification on what is meant by the matrix question.)

Comment: How did you work out 1bar + 1bar +1bar = 0bar. Im completely new to abstract algebra so forgive me if it is obvious. Also I mean if its a 2x2 matrix with elements: 1,2,2,1 going horizontal (i dont know how to latex it) then  whats the order of each of those elements

Comment: @user504498 yes, but where do the elements of the matrix come from? are they integers? or are they also in $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$? And do you mean additive order or multiplicative order? You are skipping a lot of the vital details.

Comment: @user504498 Take a look at what it means for $\bar x=\bar y$ in the integers mod $3$.   $\bar x=\bar y$ if and only if $3$ divides $x-y$.

Comment: ok so whats the order of 2bar or it doesnt exist

Comment: @user504498 Why don't you just try adding $\bar 2$ to itself until you get an answer like I did with $\bar 1$? The order *has* to exist... it 's a finite group.